# images with the same size in a plot with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to do a plot with a lot images (28 exactly), I have tried to do a script that read images and plot them, but how can I display the figures with the same size and text aligned? I don't want to see deformed figures. I don't know which are the changes that I need to do in my script. I don't have idea, I'm learning python. 
The images have different size. 
This is my script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import rcParams  
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

from pylab import text

font = {'family' : 'Helvetica',
        'size'   : 24}

plt.rc('font', **font)

# figure size in inches optional
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15,5

# read images (are 28 figures)
img_1 = mpimg.imread('path/file1.png')
...
...
img_27 = mpimg.imread('path/file27.png')


# display images
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,9, figsize=(14,6))

#fig.suptitle('Main title')
ax[0,0].imshow(img_1, aspect="auto");
ax[0,0].axis('off')
ax[0,0].title.set_text('HHP')
...
...
...
ax[2,8].imshow(img_27, aspect="auto");
ax[2,8].axis('off')
ax[2,8].title.set_text('SP10')

#imagen of the bar index
ax[3,0].imshow(img_28, aspect="auto");
ax[3,1].axis('off')
ax[3,2].axis('off')
ax[3,3].axis('off') 
ax[3,4].axis('off')
ax[3,5].axis('off')
ax[3,6].axis('off')
ax[3,7].axis('off')
ax[3,8].axis('off') 
ax[3,0].axis('off')
ax[3,0].set_position([0.27,0.2, 0.48, 0.05])

#text(-9.08, 0.6, r'$\bf{N-terminus}$', color='black', fontsize=28, fontname='Helvetica')
#text(-0.88, 0.6, r'$\bf{C-terminus}$', color='black', fontsize=28, fontname='Helvetica')
plt.show()
```

This is my out that I need to do better
 [image]

Thanks for your support.

Comment: The only one that looks a slightly different size is SP7.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: To remove the deformation caused by `aspect='auto'`, well, remove `aspect='auto'`. You might experiment with `plt.subplots(...., gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.05, 'hspace':0.05})` to encounter your favorite spacing between the subplots.

Comment: @RufusVS yes, SP7 is bigger, and  IT1, IT2, IT3, IT4, IT5 are smaller. So, do you have any idea what can be the problem or solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for your answer, I've tried, but the text is not aligned and some images are bigger (SP7 and IT1), so, the images must to be in the same size before to be plotting? Thanks for your support

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on without access to the exact images. Maybe some images have a lot of white space on one side? The very first thing you should do, is write a function to not have the same code copy-pasted all over.     If the only goal is to show 28 images with a label, matplotlib isn't the most obvious software.  There is gimp, inkscape, libreoffice, ... and many many others that make more sense.

Comment: @JohanC, thanks a lot. The reason of try it of matplotlib, is because I want a plot or one image with high and better resolution than libreoffice, office, etc.

Comment: Are you sure these programs can't obtain a better resolution than matplotlib?

Comment: @JohanC Well, I've tried before and the images are not enough good (about resolution),   do you have any protocol to use these programs? Maybe I didn't use them of correct way.